# Strange behavior of the Plotly graph when trying to autorange, using Dash clientside_callback

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, plotly-dash

There is a code that outputs a candlestick chart, and does autorange after zooming or moving.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State, Dash
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

fig.update_layout(dragmode='pan', autosize=True, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, )
config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig, animate=True, config=config, id='graph', ),
], )

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(relOut, Figure) {
        if (typeof relOut !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof relOut["xaxis.range[0]"] !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('All ok')
                //get active filter from graph
                fromS = new Date(relOut["xaxis.range[0]"]).getTime()
                toS = new Date(relOut["xaxis.range[1]"]).getTime()

                xD = Figure.data[0].x
                highD = Figure.data[0].high
                lowD = Figure.data[0].low

                //filter y data with graph display
                highFilt = xD.reduce(function (pV,cV,cI){
                    sec = new Date(cV).getTime()
                    if (sec >= fromS && sec <= toS) {
                        pV.push(highD[cI])
                    }
                    return pV
                }, [])
                //filter y data with graph display
                lowFilt = xD.reduce(function (pV,cV,cI){
                    sec = new Date(cV).getTime()
                    if (sec >= fromS && sec <= toS) {
                        pV.push(lowD[cI])
                    }
                    return pV
                }, [])

                yMax = Math.max.apply(Math, highFilt)
                yMin = Math.min.apply(Math, lowFilt)

                Figure.layout.yaxis = {
                    'range[0]': yMin,
                    'range[1]': yMax,
                    'type': 'linear'
                }


            } else {
            console.log('typeof relOut[xaxis.range[0]] !== undefined')
            }
        } else {
        console.log('typeof relOut !== undefined')
        }
        console.log('return Figure')
        return {'data': Figure.data, 'layout': Figure.layout};
        }
    """,
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('graph', 'relayoutData')], [State('graph', 'figure')]
)

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=True, )
```

But it does not work quite correctly. Before making the correct autorange, the Y-axis flies somewhere wrong, and only after that sets the correct range. I recorded a video for clarity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BInq7RQow40. Specifically here, the graph is running somewhere down. In other cases, it may run upwards, or come very close on the Y-axis.
Part of the code was taken from [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/simple-dash-app-yaxis-autoscale-on-xaxis-zoom-in-stock-market-plot/40463/5?u=liverlove). But I had to tweak it a bit, if you leave the "else" from the example, the picture jumps longer and at the end it has a completely wrong range.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

I would like to remove these flickers, and make the graph more responsive.

Crossposting on Plotly forum https://community.plotly.com/t/strange-behavior-of-the-graph-when-trying-to-autorange-using-clientside-callback/75186